# matplotlib.dates loadtxt converters date conversion python 2

Tags: date, matplotlib, converters

i am using juypter notebook and python 2.using matplotlib.dates I am unable to access the date

```
    def bytespdate2num(fmt,encoding = 'utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter    
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume = np.loadtxt('C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\stock.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters ={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})def bytespdate2num(fmt,encoding = 'utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter    
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume = np.loadtxt('C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\stock.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters ={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
```

the error message is:

```
>     ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-19-f69b316ac453> in <module>()
>       5         return strconverter(s)
>       6     return bytesconverter
> ----> 7 Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume = np.loadtxt('C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\stock.txt', delimiter=',',
> unpack=True, converters ={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
> 
> C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in
> loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows,
> usecols, unpack, ndmin)    1022     1023             # Convert each
> value according to its column and store
> -> 1024             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]    1025             # Then pack it according to
> the dtype's nesting    1026             items = pack_items(items,
> packing)
> 
> <ipython-input-19-f69b316ac453> in bytesconverter(b)
>       3     def bytesconverter(b):
>       4         s = b.decode(encoding)
> ----> 5         return strconverter(s)
>       6     return bytesconverter
>       7 Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume = np.loadtxt('C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\stock.txt', delimiter=',',
> unpack=True, converters ={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
> 
> C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.pyc in
> __call__(self, s)
>     287            return value: a date2num float
>     288         """
> --> 289         return date2num(datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(s, self.fmt)[:6]))
>     290 
>     291 
> 
> C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda2\lib\_strptime.pyc in
> _strptime_time(data_string, format)
>     476 
>     477 def _strptime_time(data_string, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"):
> --> 478     return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
> 
> C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda2\lib\_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string,
> format)
>     330     if not found:
>     331         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
> --> 332                          (data_string, format))
>     333     if len(data_string) != found.end():
>     334         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
>     
> 
> ValueError: time data u'2017-07-26' does not match format '%Y%m%d'
```

Comment: It seems your file contains dates in the format `%Y-%m-%d`, while the converter expects `%Y%m%d`. Apart, please provide a [mcve] of the issue. Also see [ask].